# Attempt at using header resulting in error: expected initializer before using

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header

I'm trying to solve an issue with a program I'm doing for college.
Whenever I try to include a header in this program, but I don't manage to make it work, here it is:
this is

```
// "numericos.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "numericos.h";

using namespace std;

double pot(double a, int b){
    if (b==0){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a*pot(a,b-1);
    }
}
```

this is "numericos.h"

```
// numericos.h
#ifndef NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
#define NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
double pot(double a, int b)

#endif // NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
```

this is another cpp in which I try to use pot:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "numericos.h"

using namespace std;

int trees(int h, int r, int t){
    int a=h*r;
    int w=t/a;
    return w;
}

double borrow(double vi, double i){
    double vf=vi*(1+i*7);
    return vf;
}

double cborrow(double vi, double i){
    double vf = vi/pot((1+i),7);
    return vf;
}
```

but I always keep getting this error:

> error: expected initializer before 'using'

I know this probably is something simple, but I can't solve it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a semicolon at the end of function declaration. Change your code as this:

```
// numericos.h

#ifndef NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
#define NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
double pot(double a, int b); // <-- note the semicolon

#endif // NUMERICOS_H_INCLUDED
```

---

Comment: thank you very much, after adding the semicolon, and testing the function in the second cpp file it works wonderful, but when i try to use it in main.cpp to test it, it still shows me this error, is there any way i have to change the way i include the header file in this case? here is main:                                                                             
    #include "numericos.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
    cout<<pot(2,5);
    }
    ("numericos.h) hasnt been changed whatsoever besides adding semicolon.)

Comment: @develupman I am able to successfully compile the program using `g++ main.cpp numericos.cpp` using main.cpp you provided.

Comment: thank you, @eozd, it seems i had a problem with the configuration of my codeblocks, really appreciate your help.